# Summarise column groups based on whether all columns within the group match a specific value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with groups of columns that start with the same letter (e.g. AA, AB, AC etc.). I need to produce a summary that counts the number of rows where all columns in each of the column groups match a specific value (e.g. 1).

If this is my dataframe (df)

```
  AA_1 AA_2 AB_1 AB_2 AB_3 AC_1 AC_2
1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1
2    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
3    1    0    1    1    1    0    0
```

I need a summary like this:

```
AA    2    
AB    1      
AC    0
```

I am able to retrieve the grouped row sums by using sapply with a list of the unique column names in the dataframe:

```
 groups <- unique(substr(names(df), 1, 2))
 sapply(groups, function(xx) rowSums(df[,grep(xx, names(df)), drop=FALSE]))
```

Output:

```
     AA AB AC
[1,]  1  2  1
[2,]  2  0  1
[3,]  2  3  0
```

But can't quite figure out how to modify this to summarise conditionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and here goes one `tidyverse` approach:

```
df <- data.table::fread("AA_1 AA_2 AB_1 AB_2 AB_3 AC_1 AC_2
 1    1    0    1    1    0    1
 1    1    0    0    0    1    0
 1    0    1    1    1    0    0") 

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    # prepare data by generating new colum from row number
    dplyr::mutate(rn = dplyr::row_number()) %>%
    # convert to long format, separating into two columns by simplified regex
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-rn, 
                        names_to = c("letrs", "nbrs"),
                        names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
                        values_to = "vals") %>%
    # build grouping by letter and row number column
    dplyr::group_by(letrs, rn) %>%
    # if all values in group are 1, then return one else 0
    dplyr::summarise(res = ifelse(all(vals) == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
    # summarise the intermediate which was per letter and row number to letters now
    dplyr::summarise(res = sum(res))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  letrs   res
  <chr> <dbl>
1 AA        2
2 AB        1
3 AC        0
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you could do it in `base R` in one step:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(df, sub("([[:alpha:]]+)_\\d+", "\\1", names(df))), 
                      \(x) {sum(apply(x, 1, \(x) all(x == 1)))}))

   [,1]
AA    2
AB    1
AC    0
```

Comment: Why split.default instead of just split?

Comment: Hi, Anoush, my friend. I realized SO started as a learning resource, became a hobby, but was becoming an obsession. Had to take some time off. You will se less from me now. I am happy to see you keep providing great answers, like in this current base R phase your are going through.

Comment: Oh that's my pleasure, You are also a brilliant coder. I understand I am also trying to scale it back as my school started and I can't afford a slip up in there.

Comment: About your question `split.default` is different from `split` as it splits the data frame by columns while the latter does it by rows. Here I first chose the similar pattern in column names and then split the data set based on similar column names so that those having something in common ended up in the same elements.

Comment: Just pick that part of code and see it for yourself. But the strange things is it hasn't been well documented anywhere.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, i could not find any documentation, this function is VERY helpful

Comment: Yeah it really is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("AA_1 AA_2 AB_1 AB_2 AB_3 AC_1 AC_2
    1    1    0    1    1    0    1
    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
    1    0    1    1    1    0    0")

#split to list using colnames
L <- split.default(DT, f = gsub("(^..).*", "\\1", names(DT)))
#value to look for
test_value <- 1
#loop over list, see if all columns (rowwise) match the test_value
answer <- lapply(L, function(x) data.table(val = nrow(x[rowSums(x == test_value, na.rm = TRUE) == ncol(x)])))
#rowbind answer using the names from the answer
data.table::rbindlist(answer, id = "group")
#    group val
# 1:    AA   2
# 2:    AB   1
# 3:    AC   0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `purrr` and `dplyr`. After extracting the groups with a regex, loop through the groups and `summarise` with `sum`.
The key here is the `if_all` function, which returns TRUE `if_all` values in the selection (`starts_with(.x)`) are TRUE (or 1):

```
groups<-map_chr(names(df), ~str_extract(.x, '^[A-Z]{2}')) %>%
        unique()

map_dfc(groups, ~df %>% summarise(sum(if_all(starts_with(.x)))))%>%
        set_names(groups)%>%
        pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'group')

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group value
  <chr> <int>
1 AA        2
2 AB        1
3 AC        0
```